# Tinkerpop3 - degree centrality

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I'm looking to find the most liked nodes so basically the degree centrality recipe. This query kind of works but I'd like to return the full vertex (including properties) rather than just the id's.

( I am using Tinkerpop 3.0.1-incubating )

```
g.V()
  .where( inE("likes") )
  .group()
  .by()
  .by( inE("likes").count() )
```

### Result

```
{
  "8240": [
    2
  ],
  "8280": [
    1
  ],
  "12376": [
    1
  ],
  "24704": [
    1
  ],
  "40976": [
    1
  ]
}
```

Comment: The result you displayed - is that GraphSON?

Comment: It's a response from the Gremlin Server Stephen.

Comment: Just checked and yeah it is GraphSON. This is the serializer;

org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for the `order` step, using an anonymous traversal passed to the `by()` modulator:

```
g.V().order().by(inE('likes').count(), decr)
```

Note: this will require iterating over all vertices in Titan v1.0.0 and this query cannot be optimized, it will only work over smaller graphs in OLTP.

To get the 10 most liked:

```
g.V().order().by(inE('likes').count(), decr).limit(10)
```

If you want to get the full properties, simply chain `.valueMap()` or `.valueMap(true)` (for `id` and `label`) on the query.

See also:

- http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#order-step
- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/gremlin-users/rt3qRKyAqts/discussion

Comment: I do need a query that will scale. Does the degree centrality recipe in my question also iterate over all vertices if I need ordering?

Comment: You typically don't want to execute traversals that don't use indices over large graphs (tens/hundreds/more millions of vertices) unless you execute them in an [OLAP style](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graphcomputer) Consider using [spark-gremlin](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#sparkgraphcompute) for example. The nice thing is that your whether you execute the traversal as OLTP or OLAP, the Gremlin statement remains the same. Only its configuration changes.

Comment: Also some [recipes](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/) are meant to be demonstrative of complex Gremlin statements and are not always practical for large scale graphs (for example, trying to execute the betweeness recipe on a very large graph, even in OLAP, will likely lead to problems given computational complexity - a problem for any betweeness algorithm for any graph database or query language). We're aware that this can be confusing and are working on improvements to take recipes beyond educational and into practical usage at any scale.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I have definitely been confused and probably over-estimated my graph databases capabilities due to this. That's okay though, I will stick to local traversals for OLTP queries and come up with another solution based on your recommendations for global style queries. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GraphSON, as it is JSON based, does not support the conversion of complex objects to keys. A key in JSON must be string based and, as in this case, cannot be a map. To deal with this JSON limitation, GraphSON converts complex objects that are to be keys via the Java's `toString()` or by other methods for certain objects like graph elements (which returns a string representation of the element identifier, explaining why you received the output that you did).

If you want to return properties of elements while using GraphSON, you will have to figure out a workaround. In this specific case, you might do:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().group().
......1>         by(id).
......2>         by(union(__(), outE('knows').count()).fold())
==>[1:[v[1],2],2:[0,v[2]],3:[v[3],0],4:[0,v[4]],5:[v[5],0],6:[0,v[6]]]
```

In this way you get the vertex identifier as the map id and in the value you get the full vertex plus the count. TinkerPop is working on improving this issue, but I don't expect a fast fix.